# Regex pattern to match letter combination of a word

Tags: regex

Currently I am developing puzzle game for kids where player needs to select correct word from the grid. I used regex to match the word.

For an example I used `([D|E|C|K]){4}` to match **DECK** because player should be able to select the word not in exact **D->E->C->K** order. Player may select it **KDEC** or **EDCK** or **KCED** or any order.

I achieved this by using `([D|E|C|K]){4}`.

But here I am facing issue, this pattern matches **EEEE** or **DDDD** or **DKDK** and etc. Simply any combination of 4 chars from the set.

Any Idea how can I modify the regex to get my desired outcome?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You could sort both selections of letters and then test equality, or keep a letter frequency count if speed is important.

Comment: While you *could* dynamically construct a regular expression for such a thing, I wouldn't recommend it. Better to count up the number of letters programatifcally and verify it.

Comment: Actually I am expecting a better regular expression to match it. I know there should be a way but I can't identify it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this is not a good job for a regex because this is not regular language. You'd better follow a simple algorithm to split the input string into characters, sort them, and rejoin into a string, do the same with the search string, then compare the  results.

See a JavaScript demo with the word `TALL`:

```js
const strings = ['TALL','LATL','TLAL','TTAL','AATT','ATL','STL'];
const search = 'TALL';
const compare_with = search.split("").sort().join("");
for (let s of strings) {
    console.log(s, ':', s.split("").sort().join("") == compare_with );
}
```

**Can we do it with a regex?** In .NET, you may use *[balancing construct](https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html)*, and it is a solution, not a workaround.

## Scenario 1: .NET regex engine specific solution

Assuming your search word is `TALL`, you may build a regex like

```
^(?:(T)|(A)|(L)|(L)){4}$(?<-1>)(?<-2>)(?<-3>)(?<-4>)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3A%28T%29%7C%28A%29%7C%28L%29%7C%28L%29%29%7B4%7D%5Cr%3F%24%28%3F%3C-1%3E%29%28%3F%3C-2%3E%29%28%3F%3C-3%3E%29%28%3F%3C-4%3E%29&i=TALL%0D%0ALATL%0D%0ATLAL%0D%0A%0D%0ATTAL%0D%0AAATT%0D%0AATL%0D%0ASTL&o=m).

**Details**

- `^`- start of string
- `(?:(T)|(A)|(L)|(L)){4}` - a non-capturing group that matches 4 occurrences of

  - `(T)` - `T` pushed on to the Group 1 capture stack
  - `|(A)` - or `A` pushed on to the Group 2 capture stack
  - `|(L)` - or `L` pushed on to the Group 3 capture stack
  - `|(L)` - or `L` pushed on to the Group 4 capture stack
- `$` - end of string
- `(?<-1>)(?<-2>)(?<-3>)(?<-4>)` - Pop a value from each of the capturing groups. If any group capture stack is not empty, return false and result in no match, else, there is a match.

## Scenario 2: Lookahead basd work-around in case all characters are unique

You may match and capture each letter from the range into a separate capturing group and add a negative lookahead before each subsequent capturing group to avoid matching a letter matched before it.

The regex will look like

```
^([DECK])(?!\1)([DECK])(?!\1|\2)([DECK])(?!\1|\2|\3)([DECK])$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sDBIhP/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([DECK])` - Group 1: a letter, `D`, `E`, `C` or `K`
- `(?!\1)` - the next char cannot be the one captured into Group 1
- `([DECK])` - Group 2: a letter, `D`, `E`, `C` or `K`
- `(?!\1|\2)([DECK])` - the next letter cannot be equal to the first and second one
- `(?!\1|\2|\3)([DECK])` - the next letter cannot be equal to the first, second and third one
- `$` - end of string

Comment: This is great. Thank you sir. What if I try to match TALL. In there as you can see two 'L' s. Could you please describe how can I match it. Then possible patterns are LATL, LLTA, ATLL, TALL and etc

Comment: @RukshanDangalla Try `^(?=(?:[^L]*L){2}[^L]*$)(?!.*([^L]).*\1)[TAL]{4}$` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sDBIhP/3))

Comment: @RukshanDangalla I updated with two more solutions. Basically, this is not the right task for a regex.